# My own exception in java - cannot find symbol

Tags: java, exception

I'm trying to create my own exceptions, but encountered a problem...

```
class MyException extends Exception {
    MyException (String w) { super ( w ); }
};


public class RozkladLiczby{

    private int[] Array;

    RozkladLiczby(int n) throws MyException { 

        try{
            Array = new int[n+2];
        }
        catch(OutOfMemoryException ex){
            throw new MyException ("Not enough memory" );
        }
    }
}
```

Compiler says it can't find symbol in catch.

```
RozkladLiczby.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
    catch(OutOfMemoryException ex){
          ^


 symbol:   class OutOfMemoryException
  location: class RozkladLiczby
1 error
```

Comment: Please post the full error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because there is no `OutOfMemoryException` in Java; there is [`OutOfMemoryError`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html).  And if there's no memory left, then what can you do?  There's no memory to create your new exception.  That's why it's an `Error` and not an `Exception`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no **OutOfMemoryException** but there is [**OutOfMemoryError**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html)

Answer (score 0):

`OutOfMemoryException`  :-  if OutOfMemoryException were to be an Exception extending MyException your custom Exception would have been thrown , since your custom exception is extending Exception class there's no chance that your custom exception would be caught in your try { } catch() { } block